# How can I tell if I'm the one who disconnected first in a GC match?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, game-center, gamekit

My iOS game has Game Center multiplayer matches. They are 1v1 battles.

If a player disconnects (that is, their state changes to `GKPlayerStateDisconnected`), such player loses the duel automatically (even if they manage to reconnect later somehow).

Suppose that players A (ID: 123) and B (ID: 456) are dueling. Then, player B loses their internet connection.

Both players receive the callback:

```
-(void)match:(GKMatch *)match player:(NSString *)playerID didChangeState:(GKPlayerConnectionState)state
```

Player A, who is still connected to the match, gets that `playerID` is 456. This is indeed right because it was player B who disconnected.

Player B, on the other hand, gets that `playerID` is 123! Why? Shouldn't it be 456 since he himself is the one who disconnected first?

Anyway, this leads to my main problem: how am I suppose to tell who disconnected first from the match?

I need Player B to realize that he's the one who disconnected, so that the player receives a prompt saying "you lost the match because you disconnected".

Comment: If it is a peer to peer game, then its not a question of "who" disconnected first. They both disconnect at the same time.